# Using elasticsearch as central data repository

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

We are currently using elasticsearch to index and perform searches on about 10M documents.  It works fine and we are happy with its performance.  My colleague who initiated the use of elasticsearch is convinced that it can be used as the central data repository and other data systems (e.g. SQL Server, Hadoop/Hive) can have data pushed to them.  I didn't have any arguments against it because my knowledge of both is too limited.  However, I am concerned.

I do know that data in elasticsearch is stored in a manner that is efficient for text searching.  Hadoop stores data just as a file system would but in a manner that is efficient to scale/replicate blocks over over multiple data nodes.  Therefore, in my mind it seems more beneficial to use Hadoop (as it is more agnostic w.r.t its view on data) as a central data repository.  Then push data from Hadoop to SQL, elasticsearch, etc...

I've read a few articles on Hadoop and elasticsearch use cases and it seems conventional to use Hadoop as the central data repository.  However, I can't find anything that would suggest that elasticsearch wouldn't be a decent alternative.

Please Help!

Comment: You mean you want to use Elasticsearch as a data warehouse?

Comment: That's what the intention is.  I really don't want to this to happen as elasticsearch is just an enterprise lucene index.  Hadoop would be far more appropriate.  I'm just looking for some agreement from the SO community, and maybe a few more reasons, before raising my concerns again

Comment: I have read once, but I find you the source now that it's not recommended to use elasticsearch as a data warehouse but I gave you some points to take into consideration before you make your decision about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd highly discourage most users from using elasticsearch as your primary datastore. It will work great until your cluster melts down due to a network partition. Even settings such as minimum_master_nodes that the ES pros always set won't save you. See this excellent analysis by Aphyr with his Call Me Maybe series:
http://aphyr.com/posts/317-call-me-maybe-elasticsearch

eliasah, is right, it depends on your use case, but if your data (and job) is important to you, stay away.

Keep your golden record of your data stored in something really focused on persisting and sync your data out to search from there. It adds extra complexity and resources, but will result in a better nights rest :)

There are plenty of ways to go about this and if elasticsearch does everything you need, you can look into Kafka for persisting all the events going into a cluster which would allow replaying if things go wrong. I like this approach as it provides an async ingestion pipeline into elasticsearch that also does the persistence.

Answer (score 9):

As is the case with all database deployments, it really depends on your specific application.

Elasticsearch is a great open source search engine built on top of Apache Lucene. Its features and upgrades allow it to basically function just like a schema-less JSON datastore that can be accessed using both search-specific methods and regular database CRUD-like commands.

Nevertheless all the advantages Elasticsearch that brings, there are still some main *disadvantages*:

- **Security** - <del>Elasticsearch does not provide any authentication or access control functionality.</del> It's supported since they have [introduced **shield**](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-know-for-security-shield-goes-ga).
- **Transactions** - There is no support for transactions or <del>processing on data manipulation.</del> Well now data manipulation is handled with **logstash**.
- **Durability** - ES is distributed and fairly stable but backups and durability are not as high priority as in other data stores.
- **Maturity of tools** - <del>ES is still relatively new and has not had time to develop mature client libraries and 3rd party tools which can make development much harder</del>. We can consider that it's quite mature now 
  with a variety of connectors and tools around it like **kibana**. But it's still not suited for large computations - Commands for searching data are not suited to "large" scans of data and advanced computation on the db side.
- **Data Availability** - ES makes data available in "near real-time" which may require additional considerations in your application (ie: comments page where a user adds new comment, refreshing the page might not actually show the new post because the index is still updating).

If you can deal with these issues then there's certainly no reason why you can't use Elasticsearch as your primary data store. It can actually lower complexity and improve performance by not having to duplicate your data but again this depends on your specific use case.

As always, weigh the benefits, do some experimentation and see what works best for you.

**DISCLAIMER:**  This answer was written a while ago for the Elasticsearch 1.x series. These critics still somehow stand with the 2.x series. But Elastic is working on them, as the 2.x series comes with more mature tools, APIs and plugins per example, security wise, like [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) or even transport clients like Logstash or [Beats](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats), etc.